# Hopping from 81 to 82

Tags: mathematics, reachability

A grasshopper is hopping around on the integers and starts its journey on the number $81$. In a jump starting from the integer $m$, the grasshopper

- may jump to any integer $m^k$ with integer $k\ge1$
- may jump to the number that results from $m$ by first cutting the decimal representation into a left piece and a right piece of two digits, and then adding three times the right piece to the left piece (for example, from $m=123456789$ the grasshopper may jump to $1234567+3\cdot89$). The left piece may be empty (for example, the jumps from $m=12$ to $0+3\cdot12$ and from $m=8$ to $0+3\cdot08$ are permitted).

No other jumps are allowed.  Is there a sequence of jumps that brings the grasshopper to number $82$?

Comment: Can the left piece be empty?  Is a jump from $081$ to $243$ permitted under the second bullet?  How about from $004$ to $12$?  How about from $105$ to $16$?

Comment: Yes, the left piece can be empty. Yes, the jumps  from 081 to 243, from 004 to 12, and from 105 to 16 are all permitted.

Comment: It seems an impossible task. I tried this in Excel: Fill A1 to A100 with nos. 1 to 100. For every cell (m,n), enter formula: **=ROUNDDOWN((m-1,n)/100,0)+(3*MOD((m-1,n),100))**. Autofill helps. I couldn't find 82 anywhere. (If your cell is, say, C5, your function will operate on B5)

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I don't think that's correct.  By my count, it takes 33 iterations to get from 81 back to 81 using jump #2:  81, 243, 131, 94, 282, 248, 146, 139, 118, 55, 165, 196, 289, 269, 209, 29, 87, 261, 185, 256, 170, 211, 35, 105, 16, 48, 144, 133, 100, 1, 3, 9, 27, 81

Comment: No matter what I do my $m$ is always divisible by 3... 82 is not divisible by 3... Therefore I conclude it's impossible.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I made a mistake while using MS Excel. You're right.

Comment: @warspyking With the second jump-option from $81$, $m$ can become $8 + 3 = 11$, which is not divisible by 3.

Comment: @warspyking: 81 --> 0+3*81=243 --> 2+3*43.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is

> not possible.

Consider the remainder of the number when divided by $13$. Initially we start with remainder $3$ ($81\equiv 3 \mod 13$), we have to get remainder $4$ ($82\equiv 4 \mod 13$).

Applying step 1, assuming that $m\equiv 3\mod 13$, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
m &\to m^k \\
3 &\to 3^1, 3^2, 3^3, \ldots \mod 13 \\
3 &\to 3, 9, 1, 3, \ldots \mod 13
\end{align}
$$

Now we know that we can at least get to $1$, $3$, and $9 \mod 13$.  Applying the same argument for the two new values, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
1 &\to 1^1, 1^2, 1^3, \ldots \mod 13 \\
1 &\to 1, 1, 1, \ldots \mod 13 \\
9 &\to 9^1, 9^2, 9^3, \ldots \mod 13 \\
9 &\to 9, 3, 1, 9, \ldots \mod 13 \\
\end{align}
$$

(Here we have explicitly shown the argument for $9$, but we could have used the fact that $9=3^2$, so the powers of $9$ must be a subset of the powers of $3$ computed earlier.)

Therefore using step 1 we can get only numbers which are congruent to 1, 3 or 9 modulo 13. Now we verify that this is still true even if we apply step 2.

If we start with the number m and apply step 2, we will get:

$$
\begin{align}
m=100a+b &\to a + 3b
\end{align}
$$

and then:

$$
\begin{align}
100a+b &\to a+3b \mod 13 \\
100a+b &\to 300a + 3b \mod 13 \\
m &\to 3m \mod 13
\end{align}
$$

Thus it is sufficient to consider the action of $m\to 3m$ on the values from earlier ($1$, $3$, and $9$):

$$
\begin{align}
3\times 1 &\to 3 \mod 13 \\
3\times 3 &\to 9 \mod 13 \\
3\times 9 &\to 1 \mod 13 \\
\end{align}
$$

(Again, we could have used the fact that all the values are powers of three instead of calculating all the transformations explicitly.)

Thus the numbers that we get through any number of jumps is always of the form $13k+1$, $13k+3$, or $13k+9$ ($m\equiv1,3,9\mod 13$).

> Since $82$ gives remainder $4$ when divided by $13$, it is not reachable.

Comment: I don't actually understand what you're saying here, but it sounds like you're saying that the final digit will always be 1, 3, or 9.  That's definitely incorrect.  See my comment on the question for the sequence of numbers derived from 81 using step 2.  There are certainly numbers that don't end in one of those 3 digits.

Comment: He's saying that all results end in one of those three digits *when divided by 13*.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Added some explanation, let me know if it is still unclear guys.

Comment: Why is 13 the magic number?

Comment: @Raystafarian, I wanted to see if the problem can be solved using congruences. For this reason observed that the second step transforms 100x+y to x+3y. Wanted x+3y to be congruent to k.(100x+y) modulo some special number in order to make the idea work. Chose k=3, such that the 3y will cancel on both sides. Ended up looking for a number which divides 300-1=299. The options were 13 and 23. Tried 13 and it worked.

Comment: $13 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 1$ which happens to be the set of numbers in the prime factorization of 81. But it is *also* $1 + 3 + 9$ which are the three resultant values for numbers in this puzzle starting from $m = 81$. *[conspiracy begins]*

Comment: Hahaha... Yeah, that's suspicious. Maybe @Gamow is trying to deliver us some more intricate message here.

Comment: I really want a generalized proof for if you start on *n* and you want to reach *n+1*

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but Step 2 doesn't necessarily break up as $100x+y$, It may also break up as $10x+y$ or $1000x+y$ or $10^m x +y$ for any $m$. For example, $14 \to 13\ \ \ \  (1 \to 0 \pmod{13})$ doesn't confirm with your proof.

Comment: @Anachor, the right piece should be a 2-digit number. I also missed that part initially and was trying to prove reachability for half an hour at least.
P.S.Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Ah, I got confused by `The left piece may be empty`.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan - Well done on the solution! However, part of the explanation is a bit hard to follow. Consider reversing the order of the three lines starting at $m \to 3m \mod 13$. Then $a\equiv 300a \mod 13$, etc., flows nicely. +1

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Marconius. I edited it, hope it is more eligible now.

Comment: I think you need to explicitly point out that 299 = 23*13, which is how you conclude that 300a = a  (mod 13).